# Why can't I put the { of an anonymous class at a new line in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

This question may be stupid but... why? Personally I like the Microsoft style where { is at the same column as the matching }. In all languages I have used, it did not matter where { was placed.

But in Kotlin, only this works.

```
image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener{
};
```

And this causes an error.

```
image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener
{
};
```

Comment: (small) nitpick: This isn't an anonymous class, it's a lambda.

Comment: If you want the {} lined up, you could put () around it. Adds code clutter, though. If Lambda is the last parameter, Kotlin makes the parenthesis optional. You CAN include them if it suits your style more. Not exactly what you're looking for, but a valid option.

e.g.
```image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
{
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#semicolons

Because your second example has the same meaning as

```
image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener;
{
};
```

a property access followed by an empty lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Braces in the same column and indented with the line above is not Microsoft style - it's known as the Allman style. It's a style I wish people would use, but sadly K&R's ancient style was pushed by Sun (Java) as the "official" style and Kotlin has followed suit.

You can do this:

```
image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener()
{
}
```

to stop Kotlin complaining.

For further information on styles, see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style